# Prevent Dialog form from closing in Smart Mobile Studio application

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

I have a modalDialog with a W3EditBox where the user enters a string that ultimately gets added to a W3ListBox on the main form

I am trying to prevent the modalDialog from closing if one of these conditions exist

1.) W3EditBox text is nil

2.) if W3EditBox text already exists in the W3ListBox list

Here is the code for calling the dialog form (has just a label, edit box, and ok and cancel buttons)

```
procedure TfrmMain.HandleAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.ShowModal('frmGoal', 'W3Panel1', 'edtTitle', InitDialog, OkResponse, nil);
end;
```

Here is the code for handling the OK response

```
procedure TfrmMain.OkResponse(AForm: TW3CustomForm);
begin
 //code here to prevent if title is nil or already exists in listbox
 W3Listbox1.Add(TfrmGoal(AForm).Title);
end;
```

On another note, I don’t understand how the W3ListBox’s IndexOf method works.
I am use to search for a string – and it looks like it wants a control

Thanks

Shane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we have a visual project with main form `MainForm` and dialog `AddDialog`. The main form contains a listbox `lbItems` and the dialog contains a wrapper panel `W3Panel1` with three child objects - an edit box `inpItem` and two buttons - `btnOK` and `btnCancel`. The AddDialog dialog is registered with a name `AddDialog`.

```
FAddDialog := TAddDialog.Create(Display.View);
FAddDialog.Name := 'AddDialog';
RegisterFormInstance(FAddDialog, False);
```

The dialog is then displayed with a simple `ShowModal` call.

```
btnAdd.OnClick := lambda
  Application.ShowModal('AddDialog', 'W3Panel1', 'inpItem', InitDialog, OkResponse);
end;
```

The simplest way to access the main form's listbox from the dialog is to provide the dialog with the reference to the main form's component. To do so, add a property to the dialog

```
property Items: TW3ListBox;
```

and then assign its value in the `InitDialog`.

```
procedure TMainForm.InitDialog(dialog: TW3CustomForm);
begin
  (dialog as TAddDialog).Items := lbItems;
end;
```

In the dialog itself you can then set up button click handlers.

```
btnCancel.OnClick := lambda Application.HideModal(mrCancel); end;
btnOK.OnClick := lambda CloseDialog; end;
```

The `CloseDialog` method will check whether the edit box is empty or equal to an already existing item in the listbox. You are correct that the IndexOf method is of no use in this case so just use a `for` loop to check all listbox items.

```
procedure TAddDialog.CloseDialog;
begin
  if inpItem.Text = '' then
    Exit;
  for var i := 0 to Items.Count - 1 do
    if Items.Text[i] = inpItem.Text then
      Exit;
  Application.HideModal(mrOK);
end;
```

BTW, the best way to access the dialog edit box from the main form is to expose it via a property in the dialog object:

```
property ItemText: string read (inpItem.Text) write (inpItem.Text);
```

The code in the main program can then access this property.

```
procedure TMainForm.OkResponse(dialog: TW3CustomForm);
begin
  lbItems.Add((dialog as TAddDialog).ItemText);
end;
```

Comment: Thank You gabr! I did expose it via a property in the dialog.  - W3Listbox1.Add(TfrmGoal(AForm).Title);  It was the Exit command that I guess I was looking for :)   Nice explanation though - it will make a nice addition to your smart book (http://www.smartprogrammer.org/)